# scanf :run time error - illegal array, pointer or other operation

Tags: c

Below is part of my program which takes N words from the user input and then stores them in an array.

However when I run the program, I got this error:

---

```
runtime error - illegal array, pointer or other operation
Execution stopped here in main() in wordchains.c at line 168:

assert(array[i] != NULL);

 -->        scanf(FORMAT_STRING, array[i]);
    //printf("scanf: %d current word:%s\n", length, array[i]);


Values when execution stopped:

i = 0
array[i] = "cast"
```

---

```
char **array;   //array as been defined as global variable
#define FORMAT_STRING "%20s"
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 20

....
//allocate memory for array to store all the words
array = malloc(sizeof(char *)*n);
assert(array != NULL);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {               //input the words
    printf("Enter word: "); 

    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    assert(array[i] != NULL);   

    scanf(FORMAT_STRING, array[i]);
```

I couldn't find anything wrong at this stage...

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE]?

Comment: @purplepsycho thank you for the link, I will check it out

Comment: regarding: `array[i] = "cast"`  the array element should NEVER contain a character string.  However it should point to a character string.  So this statement would be acceptable: `*(array[i])  == "cast"

Comment: When scanf() is called with a '%s' input/format specifier, The MAX ALLOWED character modifier must be 1 less than the length of the associated input buffer. This is because scanf() (when used with the '%s' input/format specifier) will always append a NUL byte to the input buffer.
Also, `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1. multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect. Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: https://ideone.com/XxpPEx works fine. I had to assume what you were doing since your example is not complete.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you!Yeah you got it right, it works fine one my mac but not on some other machines , I guess it is because of the different compilers that they use, it works fine when increase the word buffer by one so : MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20 + 1 = 21....

Comment: @user3629249 thank you! you are right , when I increase the input buffer size the error disappeared! But it works fine on my mac without increase the buffer ,so I guess that it has something to do with the compilers? some compliers would accept that while others might be more "cautious"?

Comment: It really depends on how long your strings are which you didn't specify. If they are 20 or more characters, with that format string you need 21 characters in your buffer to allow for the NULL character at the end. If you're overflowing the buffer it's undefined behavior. It might crash, it might not, it might behave differently with different compilers and settings.